# NgModelController $parsers and $formatters doesn't works with $render and $viewValue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, language-concepts

I am trying to understand the *$formatters* and *$parsers* of [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and with this [excellent example](http://radify.io/blog/understanding-ngmodelcontroller-by-example-part-1/)

I have created [this demo.](http://jsbin.com/xalovev/edit?html,js,console,output) But having few questions which needs to clear

Below is my main code

```
<body ng-app="app">
<input type="text" ng-model="what" placeholder="directive Value" custom-formatter>
<input type="text" ng-model="what" placeholder="model value" >
change value {{ what }}
</body>
```

and

```
angular
.module('app')
.directive('customFormatter', ['$timeout',function($timeout){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

           // format text going to user ( on view )
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue){
                console.log('MV:' + modelValue);
                if (!modelValue)  return;
                else return modelValue.toUpperCase();
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
                console.log('render called');
                console.log(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
            };

            // scope.$watch('what', function() {
            //     console.log('watcher called');
            //       ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue({
            //           what: scope.what
            //       });
            // });

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
                console.log('VV:');
                console.log(viewValue);
                if(!viewValue) return;
                else return viewValue.toLowerCase();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

my few confusion are below also with my understanding , Please correct me if I am wrong

1. in my understanding for current scenario

something changes in scope value ( i.e. in ng-model with custom directive input box ) than it means *viewValue* changed

and if something changed in input box without custom directive but same ng-model , than that means as *modelValue* changed

is that right?

2. When scope is set as isolated `{}` in custom directive then why changes reflects to other input box with same `ng-model` value

   Because we have added `require:'ngModel'`  in custom directive?

is this right?

3. When do we need to call **$render**? according to [$render document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$render)

> It is called when the view needs to be updated.

So tried

```
ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
        console.log('render called');
        console.log(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;) // this gives UPPERCASE text
};
```

But output (the other text box and {{ expression }}) doesn't show uppercase value :(

Do it need to call [`$setViewValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewvalue) at it says

> "Update the view value"

But how and where to call ? I tried

```
ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
        console.log('render called');
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue({what : scope.what }) << doesn't work
        console.log(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;) // this gives UPPERCASE text
};
```

also see the note inside special notebox saying

> if you are calling $setViewValue for an input element, you should pass
>   the input DOM value. It's also important to note that $setViewValue
>   does not call $render or change the control's DOM value in any way. If
>   we want to change the control's DOM value programmatically, we should
>   update the ngModel scope expression. Its new value will be picked up
>   by the model controller, which will run it through the $formatters,
>   $render it to update the DOM.

I do not understand this much? what means by **control** and *control's DOM*

also see a line

> "When used with standard inputs, the view value will always be a string"

but when I look in console inside $parsers => it is `Object {what: undefined}`  is that the issue?

4. tries with `scope.$watch()` but no output as UPPERCASE

   ```
    scope.$watch('what', function() {
       console.log('watcher called');
         ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue({
             what : scope.what
         });
    });
   ```

even this is never called , WHY so?

Please tell me when to use **$watch** and when to use **$render** with **$viewValue** and **$setViewValue** and how.

Comment: nobody to explain :(